# SDR: Exclude fields from json for associated object

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have an entities like this:

```
   Restaurant
      String name
      User manager

   User
     String name
     Date lastLogin
```

When I do GET /restaurants I want to inline the manager, but only with name, not with lastLogin.

When I do GET /users I want to see the full user: name + lastLogin

So I created a Restaurant-Projection and applied it as excerpt to the RestaurantRepo. But this embeds the full user into the restaurant.

When I create an excerpt project for user too, which omits the lastLogin field then it works for restaurants as expected but not for users because here the lastLogin is missing.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add the restaurant projection code to your post?

Comment: RestaurantProjection
         String getName()
         User getManager()`

Comment: Sorry for the missing formatting but it does not work... neither 4 spaces nor `

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (example from the [spring data rest documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections))

```
@Projection(name = "virtual", types = { Person.class })
public interface VirtualProjection {

  @Value("#{target.firstName} #{target.lastName}") 
  String getFullName();

}
```

So in your case this would result into this projection:

```
@Projection(name = "restaurantWithManagerName", types = { Restaurant.class })
public interface RestaurantWithManagerNameProjection {

  String getName();

  @Value("#{target.manager.name}") 
  String getManagerName();

}
```

If you want to keep the orginal structure with a nested `User` object you could achieve this by creating a custom reduced interface for the user and use it in your projection:

```
public interface UserLight {
    String getName();
}


@Projection(name = "restaurantWithReducedManager", types = Restaurant.class)
public interface RestaurantWithManagerNameProjection {

    String getName();
    UserLight getManager();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I want the manager as User object in the json, not a new (virtual) property.

Comment: I already tried it, but it does not work. Seems the json serializer uses all fields in the object not only the getters from the interface.

Comment: I suggest that you add the code of your repositories, entities and projections to your question. Information on what you already tried is always valuable and should be also included in your question. How is someone trying to answer your question supposed to know which paths you already evaluated?